# Haskell list monad and return ()

Tags: haskell

Consider the following piece of code:

```hs
foo :: [Int]
foo = do
  x <- [1..10]
  if x < 5 then pure () else [] -- Control.Monad.guard (x < 5)
  pure x

foo2 :: [Int]
foo2 = 
  [1..10] >>= \x ->
    if x < 5 then pure x else [] >>= \y ->
      pure y
```

In `foo`, I have manually inlined `Control.Monad.guard (x < 5)`, as noted in the comment.

Why does `foo` compile, even though there is `pure ()` in the code? How does the `[()]` pass the type check? Is it a special case for the do syntax? If yes, is it described anywhere?

In `foo2`, I attempted to "desugar" `foo` without the do syntax. Note that there can't be any `pure ()`, as it doesn't pass type checking.

I'm using ghc-8.8.4 if that's important.

Comment: `if x < 5 then pure () else []` compiles fine in either version, and has type `[()]`. What I think you are missing is that in a `do` block for a value of type `m b`, only the last line needs to have the precise type `m b`, other lines can have type `m a` for any `a`. When you desugar, that corresponds to different choices of `a` in the type of `>>=`, which is `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. Monadic bind doesn't care about the types "inside" the Monad, provided the function acts on the same type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several errors in your manual desugaring. One attempt that uses only `>>=` would be:

```
foo2 :: [Int]
foo2 =
  [1..10] >>= \x ->
    (if x < 5 then pure () else []) >>= \_ ->
      pure x
```

First, the parentheses are important: you're binding the result of the entire `if` expression, not performing a bind inside of its `else` branch. Second, you can't just introduce a new variable `y` and then use it in your `pure` result. Desugaring preserves the same expressions in your source code, it just moves them around a bit. So, `pure x` must desugar to `pure x`.

Hopefully you can see why this works: the type of `()` does not matter, because nobody ever looks at its value, and the result, `pure x`, has the right type regardless.

But really GHC doesn't produce quite this code: `x >>= \_ -> y` is equivalent to `x >> y`, and that's what's used for a statement in a do-block that does not bind its result to a variable. So really you get

```
foo2 :: [Int]
foo2 =
  [1..10] >>= \x ->
    (if x < 5 then pure () else []) >> pure x
```

And you can, if you prefer, use a slightly fancier operator from Functor to achieve the same result. Let's un-inline `guard`, and use `(<$) :: Functor f => a -> f b -> f a` instead of a monadic operation. `x <$ y` is the same as `y >> pure x`:

```
foo2 :: [Int]
foo2 =
  [1..10] >>= \x ->
    x <$ guard (x < 5)
```

Comment: This is much clearer, thanks! What I still don't get is that the expression in both branches of if has to have the same type, but in this case, I see different types. It is my understanding that () and [] are not the same type. But that might be a misunderstanding as well. EDIT: Oh, wait... The resulting value is going to be [()] and []. I guess that makes this clear now.